# Make the thread flag footer resizable

Tags: feature-request, flags, user-interface, moderator-tools

When I visit a thread with a pending flag as a moderator, a footer appears with information about the flags.

When there are multiple flags, the footer expands to a fairly large height. I can dismiss (“close”) it altogether, but I can't change its height. I'd like to reduce it to a smaller height while I browse the page, an enlarge it again when I want to handle the flags.

[image: screenshot]

Please allow the height of the footer to be changed by dragging the border.